# Will a Muslim with multiple wives who travels to the U.S. be charged with polygamy?

Tags: united-states, international, immigration, marriage

If you are a Muslim with multiple wives, and you travel to the U.S., will you be charged with polygamy?

What if you are also a U.S. citizen?

(I'm just curious how this works for people from Saudi Arabia, etc.)

Comment: Note that someone who intends to practice polygamy in the US cannot *immigrate* to the US, as they are inadmissible under INA 212(a)(10)(A). However, nonimmigrant travel is fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No

However, only the first wife is recognised as a wife under US law.

Please note that it is not illegal to live in a polyamorous relationship in the US: only to marry in the US while still married to another person.